# Java code of playing with members whose first letter of the name does not contain A

Tags: java

I would appreciate if someone here could help me making some changes in the code below in order to play the game only those whose name starts with every letter except the A or a letter. Here is the code:

```
public void setupPlayers() {
    checkValidPlayer();
    playerNames = new String[nPlayers];
    for (int i = 0; i < nPlayers; i++) {

        playerNames[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Jepni emrin e lojtarit " + (i + 1));

        int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
        int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "A jeni te regjistruar?", "Regjistrohu?",
                dialogButton);
        if (dialogResult == 0) {

            String enteredName = playerNames[i];

            try {
                Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
                Connection conn = DriverManager
                        .getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users/USER/Downloads/javaDB.accdb");
                Statement s = conn.createStatement();

                ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM LOJTAR ");
                List<String> dbName = new ArrayList<>();
                List<String> dbSurname = new ArrayList<>();

                while (rs.next()) {
                    // Retrieve by column name
                    dbName.add(rs.getString("Emri"));
                    dbSurname.add(rs.getString("Mbiemri"));
                }

                int k = 0;
                int a = 0;
                while (k < dbName.size()) {
                    if (dbName.get(k).equals(enteredName)) {
                        a = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    k++;
                }

                if (a == 1) {
                    if (enteredName.charAt(0) != 'a' || enteredName.charAt(0) != 'A') {

                        ResultSet rs1 = s
                                .executeQuery("SELECT ID FROM LOJTAR WHERE Emri =     '" + enteredName + "'");
                        int lojtarID = 0;
                        while (rs1.next()) {
                            lojtarID = rs1.getInt("ID");
                        }

                        ResultSet rs2 = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM PIKET WHERE ID =    '" + lojtarID + "'");

                        List<Integer> dbPiket = new ArrayList<>();

                        while (rs2.next()) {
                            // Retrieve by column name
                            dbPiket.add(rs2.getInt("Piket"));
                        }

                        int j;
                        int n = dbPiket.size();
                        int[] vektoriPikeve = new int[n];
                        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                            vektoriPikeve[j] = dbPiket.get(j);
                        }
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                "U identifikuat me sukses. Ju jeni " + dbName.get(k) + " " + dbSurname.get(k)
                                        + " dhe keni sipas hereve piket e meposhteme: \n"
                                        + Arrays.toString(vektoriPikeve));
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                "Ju dhate nje emer qe fillon me A. Ju lutem jepni nje emer tjeter!");
                        playerNames[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Jepni emrin e lojtarit " + (i + 1));
                    }
                }

                else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Emri juaj nuk u gjet ne bazen tone te te dhenave ose fillon me shkronjen A. Ju lutem regjistrohuni!");
                    registerPlayers();
                }

                // close and cleanup
                s.close();
                conn.close();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        else {
            registerPlayers();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What changes do you really want to make? You can make use of this change String methods to check your enteredname

```
if(!(enteredname.toLowerCase().startsWith("a"))){
   // do something or play
}
```

Comment: I want to play only those person whose name starts with any letter  except letter A from database or to register only those whose name does not starts with A

Comment: Yes, this will first convert the name to lower case and if it doesn't start with a, then it will do the following commands, in your case it will play.

Comment: just replace this condition if(enteredName.charAt(0)!='a' || enteredName.charAt(0)!='A')   and then put all the command for playing the game in this condition if(!(enteredname.toLowerCase().startsWith("a")))

Comment: thank u a lot @Seek Addo

Comment: you are welcome. by this part of your code    int k=0;
    int a=0;
    while(k < dbName.size()){
   if (dbName.get(k).equals(enteredName) ){
       a=1;
       break;
        }  
           k++;
               }

             if (a==1  ){ ///// what do you want to do here? if you want to go through all the names you can use for loop to do that.

Comment: i will take ur suggestion into consideration

Comment: You can go through the dbname using for loop and after that you check if the name start if "A"    for (int i = 0; i < dbname.size(); i++) {
            if (dbname.get(i).equals(enteredName)){
                //do something
            }
        }

Comment: also make sure you are not playing yourself